# I Keep Getting an SQL Syntax Error and I don't know why

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, syntax-error, primary-key

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor (
    ssn CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(30),
    specialty CHAR(30),
    yearsOfExperience INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Pharmacy (
    pharm_id CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(30),
    address CHAR(30),
    phone INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Pharm_co (
    name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    phone INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Pri_Phy_Patient (
    ssn CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(20),
    age INTEGER,
    address CHAR(20),
    phy_ssn CHAR(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (phy_ssn) REFERENCES Doctor(ssn)
);

CREATE TABLE Make_Drug (
    trade_name CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    pharm_co_name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    formula VARCHAR(100)
    FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name) REFERENCES Pharm_co(name)
);

CREATE TABLE Prescription ( 
    pre_id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
    status CHAR(20), --  canceled/ready/pending/completed 
    drop_off_time TIMESTAMP, 
    pick_up_time TIMESTAMP, 
    ssn CHAR(11),  -- patient’s ssn
    phy_ssn CHAR(11),
    pre_date CHAR(11),
    quantity INTEGER,
    trade_name CHAR(20),
    name CHAR(11),
    pharm_co_name CHAR(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Pri_Phy_Patient(ssn),
    FOREIGN KEY (phy_ssn) REFERENCES Doctor(ssn),
    FOREIGN KEY (trade_name) REFERENCES Make_Drug(trade_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name) REFERENCES Make_Drug(pharm_co_name)
);

CREATE TABLE Contract (
    pharm_id CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    start_date CHAR(11),
    end_date CHAR(11),
    text VARCHAR(4000),
    supervisor CHAR(20),
    pharm_co_name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,,
    FOREIGN KEY (pharm_id) REFERENCES Pharmacy(pharm_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name) REFERENCES Pharm_co(name)
);
```

Whenever I try to build the schema:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name) REFERENCES Pharm_co(name))' at line 5
```

I'm not sure why it keeps giving me syntax errors. I'm pretty sure this is the correct syntax for the foreign key. What should I do to fix the issue? I tried changing stuff around but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Check your commas (`,`).

Comment: missing comman before  'FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name)

Comment: Please add tag with your DBMS

Comment: Unrelated, but: `char(..)` is almost always a bad choice.

Comment: pharm_co_name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,, => pharm_co_name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve]. Part of that is "minimal". If you kept reducing your code until did not get the error then you could isolate where the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone! I was able to fix the issue. Also, thank you philipxy for those articles. I'll try to ask better questions next time, and the second article was very insightful!

Answer (score 1):

In this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Make_Drug (
    trade_name CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    pharm_co_name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    formula VARCHAR(100) <-- missing comma
   FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name) REFERENCES Pharm_co(name)
);
```

You have missed a comma after `formula VARCHAR(100)`

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a comma. make it right as-

```
CREATE TABLE Make_Drug (
    trade_name CHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    pharm_co_name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    formula VARCHAR(100), <-- add this comma
    FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name) REFERENCES Pharm_co(name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare two columns as the primary key, inline.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Make_Drug (
    trade_name CHAR(20),
    pharm_co_name CHAR(30),
    formula VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (trade_name, pharm_co_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (pharm_co_name) REFERENCES Pharm_co(name)
);
```

This also fixes the missing comma.

Comment: I didn't realize I couldn't declare two primary keys inline. Thanks for this!

Comment: @doy . . . A table can have only one primary key.  You seem to want a *composite* primary key.